# How enable mode_rewrite in windows server 2008 r2 (with php installed)

Tags: php, url-rewriting, runtime-error, windows-server-2008-r2

i have windows server 2008(r2) and i installed php and mysql using with `Web Platform Installer` in that windows.
it seems everything is ok about php and mysql.
now i want to install http://www.phpfreechat.net/ in my server.
after installation i got this error :

```
mod_rewrite must be enabled server side and correctly configured. "RewriteBase" could be adjusted in server/.htaccess file.
```

as you know .htaccess file is for linux servers.
what this error mean and how can i fix it?
i think in my server php is working under iis and there is no appache in my serevr, so how can i bypass that error?
i changed the wwwroot permission to EveryOne with no help.
also when i open wwwroot with cuteftp i can not find any permission by right click on every file (properties)

**EDIT:**
there are some folders in that project like client - server - etc
in server folder .htaccess is like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /path/to/phpfreechat/server
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<Limit OPTIONS GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mod_rewrite` is for Apache servers. [Here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) you can see how to use rewrite rules for IIS using the `URL Rewriting Module`.

You should really read [this document](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) on how to create new rewrite rules. I don't know whether it supports `.htaccess` or not, but I don't think so. Just follow the official documentation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i installed url rewrite 2.0 using with web platform installer. but that error still exists...

Comment: which part of windows server 2008 should i change for fix that error?

Comment: ugh... really thanks for the update. please give me a simple way for fix that error. i don't think that be a solution...